# Kubuntu 20.04 randomly will not turn screen on when resuming from sleep

Tags: kubuntu, display, suspend, power-management, 20.04

lspci -k output: https://pastebin.com/AhGX7SKd

here is the syslog of the event when it happened https://pastebin.com/Dxphr07f the time where the issue starts is upon wake at 19:39 which is line 412

**Computer Type:** Laptop: Lenovo E585

**GPU:** Vega 10

**CPU:** Ryzen 7 2700U

**RAM:** 8gb

**Operating System & Version:** Kubuntu 20.04, manjaro 20.0, xubuntu 20.04 (kernels 5.4 and 5.6)

**GPU Drivers:** amdgpu (mainline)

**Background Applications:** nextcloud desktop sync, redshift, pia vpn (disabled), keepassxc.

**Description of problem:** Upon wake/resume from sleep/suspend, the machine often (not always) fails to turn on the screen, forcing a system reboot. Screen is OFF not just black. The rest of the machine seems to be running (fans, keyboard lights etc)

**Troubleshooting:**

*here is a known issue in the linux kernel related to this: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=204241 and this thread too: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=248278*

Things I've tried:

- Cannot switch to terminal or gui with alt+ctrl+F2 or alt+ctrl+F3. when the screen is off/blank
- external projector DOES turn on, every time if I have it hooked up.
- tried adding kernel parameters: `amd_iommu=on iommu=pt` with no success
- I've tried disabling compositor in KDE. No success.
- tried letting it autosleep vs forced sleep, tried waking it via power button, lid opening, keyboard input. No success or difference.
- seemingly no difference between ac power vs battery
- sleep works fine on windows 10